# how to get the parameters passed by URL in my Action?

Tags: hyperlink, struts

In my jsp page I got a link like that :

```
<a href="actionEdit.do?mtitle=<%=f.getMovieTitle()%>">
```

Everything works fine in the page, but I want to get the value of mtitle in my Action page
I can't get it with request.getparameter()

thx for ur help

Comment: what version of struts are you using: 1 or 2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try:
Request.QueryString["mtitle"]

Answer (score 0):

try following code:

```
String mtitle = request.getParameter("mtitle");
```